# Trying to create Google's Advanced Search page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create Google's Advanced Search page copy. I am new to programming and I'm having 2 problems. First is that link titled "google search" should be inside the gray bar positioned at the start of the page. Second, I am trying to write css code to reverse positions of texts and their correlated input fields, because I noticed in Google's html that it is also coded in reverse and then corrected from initial position.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
.label {
    color: rgb(218, 32, 32);
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  } */

html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    size: default;
}

.navbar a {
    margin: 0 10px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align:center;

}

#textbox {
    font-size: large;
    height: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.graybar{
    background-size: 75% 50%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    font: 13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    }

#image {
    height: 33px;
    width: 92px;
    margin: 15px;
    }  
    
 .margin { 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   
 }   


body {
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Advanced Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="graybar">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id=image>
        <div class=navbar>
            <a href="index.html">
                Google Search
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Advanced Search</div>
    <h3 style="font-weight:normal">Find pages with...</h3>
    <form action="https://google.com/search">
        <input class="margin" value autofocus="autofocus" id="xX4UFf" name="as_q" type="text">
        <label for="xX4UFf" class="float">all these words:</label>
        <br>
        <input class="margin" value autofocus="autofocus" id="CwYCWc" name="as_epq" type="text">
        <label for="CwYCWc" class="float">this exact word or phrase:</label>
        <br>
        <input class="margin" value autofocus="autofocus" id="mSoczb" name="as_oq" type="text">
        <label for="mSoczb" class=float>any of these words:</label>
        <br>
        <input class="margin" value autofocus="autofocus" id="t2dX1c" name="as_eq" type="text">
        <label for="t2dX1c" class="float">none of these words:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</htmL>
```

[Here is how website looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqQq8.png)

Comment: Can you not change your HTML? `<br>` tags really shouldn't be used there, and you could use flexbox for the criteria rows to reverse the order of input/label. (Also you're missing some `"` marks in places, eg `<div class=navbar>` ... and your inline CSS is really going to start throwing you off.)

Comment: I'm struggling man XD. This is my first ever coding experience and I will update the page how it'll go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can change your HTML, flexbox is the solution to both of your issues.

Let's start with your header. You need your image and your text to be both in the grey box, with the image on the left side and the text on the right side.

If you set your header to use `display: flex`, then you can specify `justify-content: space-between` to tell the browser to render the child elements with as much space as is possible between them. For two children, that will result in the first child being on the left, and the second child being on the right. If there were more children, they'd be spaced evenly between (eg left, middle, right for three children etc.)

In your case, this would simply require adding the appropriate styling to the `.graybar` class which is serving as your header:

```
.graybar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
.graybar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  background-size: 75% 50%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font: 13px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  size: default;
}

.navbar a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#image {
  height: 33px;
  width: 92px;
  margin: 15px;
}

body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="graybar">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id=image>
  <div class=navbar>
    <a href="index.html">Google Search</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've left the other styling as you had in your original.

CSS's flexbox is extremely powerful; you can use it for your other issue with the labels/inputs as well, if you can modify your HTML. Looking at the actual Google advanced search page [here](https://www.google.com/advanced_search), your HTML doesn't actually look anything like the original, so I'm assuming you're not restricted to keeping the same HTML as you have in your original post.

Let's instead structure our HTML like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" id="allwords" >
  <label for="allwords">All these words</label>
</div>
```

We can now apply `display: flex` to each row and leverage the `flex-direction` property to reverse the order of the children so that the label is displayed prior to the input.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" id="allwords">
  <label for="allwords">All these words:</label>
</div>
```

Generally I wouldn't recommend doing it like this, but I'm equally unsure why you're trying to force inputs before labels in your HTML. :)

For more information about CSS's flexbox, I highly recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) from CSS-Tricks.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I tried to place inputs after labels but the inputs followed labels pattern. Some of them were moved more on the right then others. I wanted them to be perfectly aligned from top to bottom. Will flex solve my problem if I put labels first as I did previously?

Comment: I could send an image how it turned out at first.